# Match patten rule before explicit rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to generically add some behaviour to every target in a Makefile, without modifying the targets.

My current attempt is thus:

```
%: $*
     @echo 'Logging $* target'
.PHONY: test
test:
     @echo 'Inside explicit test target'
```

When I run `make test`, I'd like to match the `%` pattern rule, which would execute `test` as a prerequisite (`$*` expanding to the pattern stem), and then log the target that was run.

```
$ make test
Inside explicit test target
Logging test target
```

**Instead**, what happens is that `make test` matches the explicit `test` target (presumably since it's a closer match):

```
$ make test
Inside explicit test target
```

How can I get this to work, without changing the explicit test target?

EDIT:
Another attempt...

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%: $$*
     @echo 'Logging $* target'
```

results in

```
$ make test
make: Circular Makefile <- Makefile dependency dropped.
inside actual test target
```

Comment: Would you be willing to use an additional makefile?

Comment: If that helps, sure?

Answer (score 1):

I appears from your own answer, which has beaten me to the punch, that
you're concerned only to trigger a preliminary action for targets *that are
mentioned on the commandline* - `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`. From the posting I took
it that you wanted such an action for "every target in a Makefile", which
would include all targets that are prerequisite to the commandline targets or,
if there are no commandline targets, to the default target.

Anyhow, you may still be interested in a solution to the more general problem.

You want a preliminary action to be executed before the recipe for every target.
Your question is: *how to match a patten rule before explicit rule?*

This is an XY way of posing the problem, because `make` will consult pattern
rules to find a way of making a target only if you *don't* give it an explicit
recipe. You know, for example, that `make` has a pre-defined pattern rule for
making an `.o` file from a `.c` file. Even so, if my makefile is:

```
test.o:
    @echo $@
```

then `make` prints `test.o`, without any attempt to find `test.c` and compile it.
And if my make file is:

```
test.o: test.c
    @echo $@

test.c:
    @echo $@
```

then `make` prints:

```
test.c
test.o
```

needing no resort to the pattern rule. But if my makefile is:

```
test.o: test.c
```

Then `make` says:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'test.c', needed by 'test.o'. Stop
```

So you can't do what you're after in the way your question supposes,
because the preliminary action you want to provoke from the pattern
rule could be provoked only if there were *no other action* for the target.

In that case the reasons for the failures of your two posted attempts are fairly academic,
and you may wish to scroll to **The Chase**.

In your first attempt, with:

```
%: $*
    @echo 'Logging $* target'
```

The pattern rule - which is unemployed by `make test` - is equivalent to:

```
%:
    @echo 'Logging $* target'
```

because `$*` only assumes a value in the recipe, not in the pattern rule. You
can make this pattern rule be employed by making any target for which the
makefile does *not* provide a recipe, e.g. `make nonsuch` will print `Logging nonsuch target`;
but that is of no use.

The second attempt, with:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%: $$*
     @echo 'Logging $* target'
```

does the right thing to create the rule you intend to create. But the
meaning of that rule is:

```
<target>: <target>
     @echo 'Logging <target> target'
```

making every target to which this rule is applied a prerequisite of itself.
Inevitably this will result in a circular dependency error for all such targets.
As you saw, this circularity does not affect the your `test` target because
it has an explicit recipe and does not employ the rule. But it does provoke
the surprising error:

```
make: Circular Makefile <- Makefile dependency dropped.
```

That happens because the first target that `make` automatically considers is
*the makefile itself*. Unlike the `test` target, you have no recipe for
the makefile; so the pattern rule applies to it, making the makefile dependent
on itself.

**The Chase**

You can achieve what you want by a different approach. In a actual project
it is more than likely that in any makefile you can compute a list of
all possible targets. From this you can generate a corresponding list of
auxiliary targets, say, *target* => *target.prelim*, where the
sole purpose of *target.prelim* is to provoke, when it should and not
otherwise, the required preliminary action for *target*; and you can get `make`
to generate a list of [order-only rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html), *target*: | *target.prelim*,
for each *target*, such that *target.prelim* will not be considered in determining whether *target*
must be made, but will be made before *target* whenever *target* needs to be made.

Here is an illustration:

```
SRCS := main.c foo.c
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
TARGETS := all prog $(OBJS)
PRELIMS := $(patsubst %,%.prelim,$(TARGETS))

define prelim_rule =
$(1): | $(1).prelim
endef

$(foreach target,$(TARGETS),$(eval $(call prelim_rule,$(target))))

.PHONY: all

all: prog

prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(PRELIMS) prog

%.prelim:
    @echo "Logging target $(@:%.prelim=%)"
    @touch $@
```

And a sample session:

```
$ make
Logging target all
Logging target main.o
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
Logging target foo.o
cc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
Logging target prog
cc    -o prog main.o foo.o 
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
$ make clean
rm -f main.o foo.o all.prelim prog.prelim main.o.prelim foo.o.prelim prog
$ make main.o
Logging target main.o
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
$ make main.o
make: 'main.o' is up to date.
$ # A prelim can't out-date its target...
$ touch main.o.prelim
$ make main.o
make: 'main.o' is up to date.
```

Comment: Very cool, and thanks for the explanation of what I learnt the hard way :) Unfortunately this approach relies on being able to list the targets, which I can't (I'm an included Makefile, and I don't control the parent makefile).

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this isn't answering my question as asked, but it has the effect I want - executing a `shell` command as late in the `Makefile` processing as possible.

```
MYVAR?=foo
.PHONY: test
test:
    @echo 'Inside test target'

LOG=$(shell echo 'Logging $(MAKECMDGOALS), myvar=$(MYVAR)' > log)
.SECONDEXPANSION:
force: $$(LOG)
```

`LOG` is a deferred variable, so is not expanded until Make evaluates the prerequisite list of the `force` target.

In a single Makefile, the `.SECONDEXPANSION:` part is not needed, since the `force` target is evaluated after `MYVAR` is set.

However, if I move the `LOG` variable and `force` variable into a sub-makefile, it would be easy to `include subMakefile` before the `MYVAR?=` line - which would not work. 
By specifying `.SECONDEXPANSION` for `force`, the reliance on ordering is removed.